# Icomoon font generator: Failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have some icon fonts being used from https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

When I use the generated CSS it works fine from style tags on the actual HTML page:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:    url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3');
    src:    url('fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?hsw0h3') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?hsw0h3') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?hsw0h3#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

When I put the CSS in my CSS file and adjust the paths:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?hsw0h3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?hsw0h3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?hsw0h3#icomoon') format('svg');
    src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3');
}
```

I am getting this error in the developer console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///C:/Users/Daisy/Desktop/softstack%20consulting/fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I dont understand why it fails to decode the font just by moving the CSS and changing it's path. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the `src` with this line:
`src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?hsw0h3');`

Look more closely at the original CSS. Those different formats separated with comma should be part of the second `src` value, not the first one.