# Browser sometimes uses the wrong font to render icons, resulting in garbled text

Tags: css, icons, font-face

I'm having an intermittent problem with Chrome not rendering the correct fonts to display icons.

I'm using icomoon.io to create a custom set of icons as a font, and I'm using the following css (auto-generated by icomoon) to display those custom icons.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'eIconFont';
    src: url('fonts/eIconFontV3.eot?kmqo7q');
    src: url('fonts/eIconFontV3.eot?kmqo7q#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/eIconFontV3.woff2?kmqo7q') format('woff2'), url('fonts/eIconFontV3.ttf?kmqo7q') format('truetype'), url('fonts/eIconFontV3.woff?kmqo7q') format('woff'), url('fonts/eIconFontV3.svg?kmqo7q#eIconFontV3') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="eIcon-"], [class*=" eIcon-"] {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: 'eIconFont' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    /* Enable Ligatures ================ */
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
    font-feature-settings: "liga";
    -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;
    font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.eIcon-support:before {
    content: "\e93b";
}
.eIcon-collapse:before {
    content: "\e935";
}
.eIcon-expand:before {
    content: "\e936";
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<span class="eIcon-support" title="Support">
    ::before
</span>
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

Looking at Chrome dev tools, I can see that the font files themselves are loading fine from our CDN, but I have noticed that under *Elements > Computed > Rendered Fonts* it says `Times New Roman`, when the value is usually `eIconFontV3`. It's odd that the browser is trying to use Times New Roman, when the font-family set on the body is `'Gotham Light', Arial, sans-serif`.

This bug only happens rarely, and is pretty hard to reproduce.

Comment: Are there supposed to be two `src` values for `@font-face`? It seems like one would overwrite the other.

Comment: @showdev I'm not sure why there are two `src`, that's just what icomoon.io generates. Extra cautious fallback perhaps?

Comment: That could be. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582117/icomoon-font-generator-failed-to-decode-downloaded-font), but I'm not sure whether it's related. Do you see any error like that?

Comment: @showdev No, unfortunately no errors show in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into the problem. If you use [sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) and cause the problem, maybe the bellow detail will help you.

I use sass to compile SCSS files to CSS files, and I found sass convert the escape string(e.g. `\E91E`, hex `5C45393145` ) to the real utf-8 value(``, hex `EEA49E`), but the [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) doesn't do that. And the conversion causes the text to garbled sometimes when using Chrome. [Here](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1219) has more detail about the issue.

My temporary solution is to use node-sass instead of sass to compile SCSS files.

Comment: While I understand the difference in the resulting CSS between using sass and node-sass, I don't understand why Chrome (or any webkit browser) sometimes uses Times New Roman rather than the specified icon font. This is causing me a real headache.

Comment: @lhtin thank you very much for the work you put in on the linked issue in the sass repo. Your explanations and examples were very helpful in helping me track down why this is happening in the app I work on.