# Troubles with Webpack, SASS, and FontAwesome

Tags: webpack, sass, font-awesome

I have a big project, hosted on Google Cloud App Engine and now I am experiencing some troubles with Webpack. I use Webpack to compile TypeScript and at the same time to compile several SASS files with the following configuration:

```js
{
    test: /\.sass$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                url: false,
            }
        },
        {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                        ["postcss-preset-env",],
                    ],
                },
            },
         },
         "sass-loader"
     ],
},
```

It works pretty cool, but sometimes my FontAwesome looks like this:

[image: Corrupted icons example (screenshot)]

These icons get corrupted very rarely (even when I don't change files themselves, so it looks like it depends on the network).

In SASS files I have FontAwesome classes with Unicode escape-sequences, but Webpack compiles them straight into regular characters:

[image: Compiled CSS expample screenshot]

FontAwesome is loaded by @font-face rule and it uses font-display: block:

```
@font-face
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'
    font-display: block
    src: url('/fonts/fa/fa.woff2?v=4') format("woff2"), url('/fonts/fa/fa.woff?v=4') format("woff"), url('/fonts/fa/fa.ttf?v=4') format("truetype")
```

Does anybody know why my FontAwesome might get corrupted (especially so periodically)? Is it because something happens to the encoding during the network transfer? Can I just make Webpack to not process Unicode escape-sequences?

Answer (score 2):

**To fix**: with webpack use [css-unicode-loader](https://github.com/styzhang/css-unicode-loader)

**Explanation**: looks like Chrome (maybe other browsers) has bug and sometimes doesn't render font-icons when it's converted from sass/scss to css (from escape-string to utf8):

```
.foo {
  &:before{
    content:"\e949"
  }
}
```

To

```
.foo {
  &:before{
    content:"" // it's issue
  }
}
```

Related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800083/browser-sometimes-uses-the-wrong-font-to-render-icons-resulting-in-garbled-text)

Comment: I believe this affects all chromium-based browsers. so Brave, Chrome, Edge, Opera, Safari are all affected

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use the sass unquote function to your content.
Example: content: unquote('"\\e949"');

which will give you the following output in your css after webpack build:
content: "\e949";